# customizing woocommerce address fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to edit, or add some fields to, woocommerce billing and shipping address in checkout page, profile page and everywhere in which the fields are displayed.
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

revving an old question but

```
function override_default_address_fields( $fields ) {

    unset($fields['company']);

    foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
       $fields[$key]['label_class'] = 'sr-only';
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_default_address_fields' );
```

all the available fields can be found in includes/class-wc-countries.php -> public function get_default_address_fields()

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to edit or add new fields in woo commerce checkout page you can try with hard code and with woo commerce checkout field editor plugin

Comment: thank you for response, i test this plugin, this just edit checkout fields. i want to edit fields in user profile too.

Comment: oky if my post is helpfull for you then you can accept my ans